# Possible to pipe stdout directly to web browser?

Tags: macos, shell, web, browser

I have some python utilities that generate HTML output. Instead of saving to a temporary file, and opening that in a web browser, I would like to be able to just redirect the output to the browser to preview it. For example, something like:

```
myscript.py | open /Applications/Safari.app
```

Is there any way to do such a thing? I am on OS X.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
curl https://www.google.com | bcat
```

---

If you can have ruby on your system you may install [`bcat`](https://rtomayko.github.io/bcat/):

```
gem install bcat
```

Make sure you have the gem binary folder in your path, e.g.:

```
/home/{YOUR_USER_NAME}/.local/share/gem/ruby/{VERSION}/bin
```

in my case that would be:

```
/home/philipp/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin
```

Then you'll have `bcat` command at your disposal in which you can pipe in html and which will then open your browser as shown above.

Comment: Thanks! That worked great :^)

Answer (score 2):

About the best I can come up with is encoding the HTML as a `data:` URL and making a browser open it:

```
import webbrowser, base64

html = "<b>hello world</b>"
b64url = "data:text/html;base64," + base64.b64encode(html)
webbrowser.get("safari").open(b64url)
```

However, this doesn't seem to work reliably for any browser other than Safari. I'm not sure how well it will work with large pages, either; the URL may eventually get too large to handle.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know about the `webbrowser` library. Will try to test its limits.

Comment: It's extremely limited, I'm afraid. The functionality I'm demonstrating here is nearly everything it supports.

Answer (score 0):

`open` utility in macOS is quite powerful, check `man open`. Although `-f` argument description mentions default text editor, it actually works with all apps. So for your case this should work:

```
myscript.py | open -f -a safari
```

Unfortunately `open` just saves your input to a temporary `.txt` file and browser treats it as plain text so you can't render html that way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unclear what you are saying... It doesn't work after all?

Comment: It displays plain text just fine – if that's what you want. It just won't render HTML